# how to write a subquery inside join statement

Tags: javascript, postgresql, join, subquery, knex.js

This is my subquery:

```js
const subquery = async () => {
  return await knex.select('*')
    .from('contracts')
    .where('estate_id', '=', estateid)
}
```

And this is how I'm inserting it into the join statement:

```js
const data = await knex('clients')
  .join(await subquery(), 'clients.client_id', 'contracts.client_id')
```

But this result in an error, my question is what is the proper way to write a subquery and then include it inside a join statement, using async/await.

In the docs there is a mention on subqueries but is not for the join case and I fail at trying to adapt it to a join case:

```js
knex('users').where('votes', '>', 100)

const subquery = knex('users')
  .where('votes', '>', 100)
  .andWhere('status', 'active')
  .orWhere('name', 'John')
  .select('id');

knex('accounts').where('id', 'in', subquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to await the subquery, you can just pass a function representing the subquery as the first argument to the join. i.e.

```js
const data = await knex('clients')
    .join(function() {
        this.select('*')
        .from('contracts')
        .where('estate_id', '=', estateid);
    }, 'clients.client_id', 'contracts.client_id');
```

Note that the reference to knex changes from `knex` to `this` once inside the subquery. If you want to keep the subquery separate you should be able to do it like

```js
const subquery = function() {
    this.select('*')
    .from('contracts')
    .where('estate_id', '=', estateid)
}
const data = await knex('clients')
  .join(subquery, 'clients.client_id', 'contracts.client_id')
```